# Crypto-js cual es el initialization vector (iv) si no se especifica?

Tags: javascript

En mi aplicación se utiliza Cryto-js para encriptar y desencriptar por medio de Triple Des. En todo el proceso nunca se especifica el iv.

Aquí surge mi pregunta. ¿cuál es el iv por defecto que usa Cryto-js para Triple Des?

Por ejemplo, aquí no se especifica el iv y hace la encriptación.

```
return TripleDES
      .encrypt(enc.Utf8.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data)), this.genKey(this.key), PayloadCrypto.CONFIG)
      .ciphertext.toString(enc.Base64);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontre la respuesta.

Al no ser especificado Cryto-js crea un bloque completo de 0x00 para el iv según el tamaño del algoritmo.